# xamarin android oauth 403 error - disallowed_useragent

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin.android, google-oauth

I am new to xamarin android. I am trying to implement OAuth in xamarin android with Google as Identity provider. I have registered my app with google and got the client id and Client secret which I am using when user click on login button as below.

```
void OnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            Constants.ClientId,
            Constants.ClientSecret,
            Constants.Scope,
            new Uri(Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
            new Uri(Constants.RedirectUrl),
            new Uri(Constants.AccessTokenUrl));

        authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
        authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;

        var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
        presenter.Login(authenticator);
    }
```

It redirects to google but gives 403 error as 'disallowed_useragent'. 
According to [this](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html), google "no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as web-views"

After going through some forums and stackoverflow questions, I come to know that
**chromecustomtabs** need to be use.

So here I have two questions

1. Is there alternate solution to chromecustomtabs?
2. If above answer is no, then if I understand correctly then I need to add below code in my project. My question is what modification needs to be done in OnLoginClicked function? Does the OAuth2Authenticator required in that case?

My code:

```
var mgr = new CustomTabsActivityManager (this);
mgr.CustomTabsServiceConnected += delegate {
mgr.LaunchUrl ("http://xamarin.com");
};
mgr.BindService ();
```

Any suggestions/links would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [topic](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86415/google-auth-error-disallowed-useragent). [Xamarin Auth 1.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xamarin.auth/)  supported CustomTabsIntent.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your section question:

There is a parameter on `OAuth2Authenticator` called `isUsingNativeUI`.  You must set it to true.  This will cause Xamarin.Auth to use the CustomTabs service inside Android rather than the webview.

Your code becomes:

```
    var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
        Constants.ClientId,
        Constants.ClientSecret,
        Constants.Scope,
        new Uri(Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
        new Uri(Constants.RedirectUrl),
        new Uri(Constants.AccessTokenUrl),
        null,
        true); // <--  This is it isUsingNativeUI
```

I wish it were the default.

Comment: >  wish it were the default.

It will be in the future. The problem is - the google is only provider that requires native ui, some other providers can be setup, but this is not mandatory.
It is false by default for compatibility reasons (backward compatibility)  and it will stay for some time.