# Error 403: disallowed_useragent In Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm nooby in xamarin and I try to add 2 lines to resolved the error Error 403: disallowed_useragent
base on youtube video I found. This video show how to resolved the error on android studio and not on xamarin

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYGRh5vpSn8

the 2 lines I need to add is :

1. public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19";
2. webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);

Thanks for your help and understanding

Comment: There is no useful context here.  What are you doing with Webview that causes this?  Where is the relevant code?

Comment: When I'm setting OAuth2, I get this with google authentication like in the video. I'm displaying the OAuth2 page in a WebView (from keycloak server), And I tried also by using Xamarin.Auth NuGet and the same problem.

Comment: Xamarin Auth has not been updated in 2 years.  Use Essentials instead

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve my problem because Google authentication is made "inside" of the Keycloak authentication page, which is an HTML page. So I need to resolve the error by founding how to add these 2 lines

Comment: According to the Xamarin Auth docs, workarounds to fake the user agent are a violation of Google's TOS.  Good luck.

Comment: hmm ... it works well if I'm doing it in google chrome or any other browser, It doesn't work in Xamarin only :(

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157165/xamarin-android-oauth-403-error-disallowed-useragent) may help you.